# How do I cut a bezier without subdividing?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, image, bezier-curves

I'm kinda new so please don't bash me. So i have this part thats penetrating the head and im trying to cut it but idk how, i cant do subdivide since its a bezier so im kinda stuck ( ´△｀)
https://gyazo.com/498f426bdbe571bab0b9f5fb18651d90 <-- example

Comment: I think you have no choice but move the vertex out of your shape or subdivide the segment and dissolve vertices

Comment: Why don't you want to subdivide?